# MySQL Percentage Query

Tags: mysql

I need to query my table to show a count of rows as a percentage. I have a table called `user_task` and I need to show the percentage of tasks that the user has completed.

So for every `user_task` where the `date_completed = '0000-00-00'` as a percentage of the `user_task.date_completed != '0000-00-00'`.

Is this possible to do in one query?

Comment: Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you post what you have tried till now

Comment: Thank you for your reply @LalitMehra I am able to sum the number of entries where the date is set to '0000-00-00' or otherwise with the following:

SELECT IF(date_completed = '0000-00-00', 1, 0) AS completed
FROM user_task
WHERE user_id = 1;

However I don't know how I can use the result to perform the percentage calculation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the lines of

```
select sum(completed)/count(*) from 
(SELECT IF(date_completed = '0000-00-00', 1, 0) AS completed
 FROM user_task WHERE user_id = 1) s1;
```

i.e. use your existing query as a basis for the calculation.